# powershell script center - what do these mean?

Tags: powershell

I'm learning to use powershell and it's not clear to me what is meant by the 4 Powershell subheaders in the image[image]; in this case, looking at the Get-FolderItems.ps1 function at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7

Are they meant to represent different examples of how the function can be used? Or am i supposed to use them in a specific sequence (e.g. first . .\Get-FolderItem.ps1 then Get-FolderItem -Path .\mypath, etc)

Answer (score 2):

The first cmdlet is to load the cmdlet from the **ps1** file using the **dot sourcing** syntax.

```
. .\Get-FolderItem.ps1
```

You should already be in the same directory as that file. Also, your execution policy should allow execution of this script. You can set the Execution policy to either **RemoteSigned** (default mode in Windows Server 2012 R2 onwards) or **Unrestricted** (not recommended but ok for dev/test purposes).

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

**Rest** are the examples of using the cmdlet `Get-FolderItem`.

Read more about that cmdlet in this blog: [List All Files Regardless of 260 Character Path Restriction Using PowerShell and Robocopy](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/)

Comment: @val If this helped answer your question, please mark as answer by click on the tick mark under the arrows beside my answer. If you need more details please let us know.